# How is average value in conjunction with group by is different from straightforward average in subquery?

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

Can anyone help me with the below?

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, SUM (LineTotal) AS TotalSales
FROM SALES.SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING SUM (LineTotal)>
--query1
(
SELECT AVG (SumCalc.SumValues)
FROM (SELECT SUM(LineTotal) AS SumValues
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
) AS SumCalc

)
```

---

---query2

```
SELECT AVG (LineTotal)
FROM SALES.SalesOrderDetail
```

why is query 1 and query 2 giving different results? I am just trying to make the query 1 simple. How does the use of GROUP BY Clause make a difference here? When I ran the sum in different queries the value came to be identical, and i am not sure how the way avg is calculated is different here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the difference between a weighted average and a simple average.  Consider this simple example:

```
code     value
 A         1
 A         1
 A         4
 B         4
```

The overall average is simply 2.5 -- (1 + 1 + 4 + 4) / 4.

If we aggregate by the code first and then take the average, we have:

```
code     average
  A         2
  B         4
```

The average of these two rows is 3, quite different.

Simply put:  The average of averages on aggregated data can be quite different from the overall average.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That was pretty basic.

Comment: @SnehasishChoudhury . . . It is actually quite subtle -- and the result of more misunderstandings than you might realize.

Comment: @Scratte . . . An off-by-1 error!  Thank you for pointing out my arithmetic failures.